# A PHP session for all requests

Tags: php, session, telegram-bot

*I have read some similar questions but all of them about answering to a human client behind a browser which is not my case. I need to answer another server using sessions, so no browser and cookie!*

**What I'm working on:** I'm creating a telegram bot (using telegram `webHook` mode and PHP) which gets a user's message (handed by telegram server) and checks if it is the right answer. In each of the states of Yes/No, bot will do the proper action. So there is a database here to read the right answer from and lots of recieved messages to be checked. The whole code would be executed for each message.

**Question:** How can I use sessions to respond to all of the requests comming from a server (telegram server)? Since there is a lot of requests, so retrieving information from MySQL database each time whould cause low performance. Is there any other better solution for that?

Comment: DB query can be not so expensive. BTW, php sessions are stored in files, so you can store data in your own file (JSON encoded can be a solution).

Comment: Which one is faster? DB or file?

Comment: reading a file can be faster, but if you have to process it (and I think that you want it) db is faster. Also note that mysql query are generally cached.

Comment: So I'm gonna use DB, since it seems the better solution.
Thanke you for your help @fusion3k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS fusion3k told you, sessions are stored in files and are not designed for handle a large amount of data. In the same way, session needs cookie for working.

If yout information does'nt change between request, you can use [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) for caching.